# Optimizing a Pandas apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, optimization

I have the following two Pandas DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['New York', 'London', 'New York'], 
       'date': [
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'), 
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02'), 
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-03')
        ]})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['London', 'London', 'New York', 'New York'],
       'date': [
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-07'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-08'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01'),
                 pd.Timestamp('2022-01-08')
        ]})
```

Then, I add another column to the first DataFrame, calculated by the following apply:

```
from datetime import timedelta

def add_7_days_ago(x, df_2):
    dates_df_2 = df_2[df_2['name'] == x['name']]
    x_date = x['date']
    seven_days_ago = x_date + timedelta(-7)
    df_7_days_ago = df_2[df_2['date'] == seven_days_ago ]

    return 1*(len(df_7_days_ago) > 0)

df_1['7_days_ago'] = df_1.apply(lambda x: add_7_days_ago(x, df_2), axis=1)
```

This approach is plain and simple, however it does not scale for large datasets (i.e. if df_1 and df_2 have > 100k rows) and if the lambda function is more complex. How can I optimize it, preferably by vectorizing it?

Basically, how can I vectorize a function that needs to filter for a certain column's value in each row?

Comment: Please share a working reproducable code `7_days_ago` is an invalid name, and after fixing there is still an error

Comment: @azro, Thanks for the notice. I coded it just to present the idea, but now it should be a working example

Comment: @AlexandarZaharyan. Can you explain your logic, please? It's not so obvious for me.

Comment: @Corralien, my idea is that for each row in df_1, I want to filter those rows in df_2 that have the same 'name' value and then check if in that subset of df_2 there is a `date` that meets a certain condition (in that case 7 days before the 'date' value of the current row in df_1). Does that make sense?

Comment: OK. but `x.name` is not what you think. You should replace by `x['name']` else you will have `0` and `1` instead of `New York` and `London`.

Comment: @Correlean, Yes, for each name there can be multiple dates, hence multiple rows with the same name

Comment: Please provide a such example.

Comment: You code is in the right direction. The only problem is you are repeating the calculations.  Consider doing the calculations once for every city.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use `merge` to lookup names between your two dataframes then compute the diff between dates:

```
out = df_1.merge(df_2, on='name', suffixes=('', '2'))
out['7_days_ago'] = out['date'].sub(out.pop('date2')).eq(pd.Timedelta(days=7)).astype(int)
print(out)

# Output
       name       date  7_days_ago
0  New York 2022-01-08           1
1    London 2022-01-01           0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I think this is not scalable if the two dataframes are big (>100k rows) and each 'name' can have multiple dates. Updated the example in the question accordingly.

Comment: @AlexandarZaharyan did you just say `merge` will not work? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @onyambu, yes, if I'm not mistaken the merge will blow up the dimensionality of the resulting DataFrame.

Comment: You need a `groupby` after that. It's not problem if you update your post with the output.